# background-cover adds a blank 1px-line in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I have a div and a background-cover attached to its div. It doesn't work with Chrome : it, for some images, adds a blank line (horizontal, or vertical, it depends).

**HTML**

```
<div class="div_image"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid red;
    background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-v7UK1A8fw3A/UJXR5Vc5RjI/AAAAAAAAHuY/aWzZuSv8-jI/s250/Laika.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/rTBVs/2/.

Comment: Why is the url inside the div tag? That seems like asking for broken code.

Comment: This was a mistake, now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

hi i have tested this and it works,

```
.div_image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid red;
    background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-v7UK1A8fw3A/UJXR5Vc5RjI/AAAAAAAAHuY/aWzZuSv8-jI/s250/Laika.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

i have removed (no-repeat center center) from the background value

cheers

Comment: When you make this, there is another problem. Here : http://jsfiddle.net/55puX/, there is a line in the bottom of the image which is the same than the first line of the image.

Comment: The image you are trying to squeeze down in size has a height of 220px and width of 197px to maintain aspect ratio change the div height to 90px and width to 100px.

Comment: I don't want to maintain aspect ratio. I just want to display this image as a background cover. It should works with all formats.

Answer (score 0):

There is no blank line for me in Chrome ... but it sounds like a problem with the image to me. The URL you have on the div doesn't belong there, though. That's not where a url belongs, and it may be causing a problem in your browser.

Comment: The URL was for another purpose, I forgot to remove it. But even without the URL, I've still a blank line...